# How do you pan the screen without moving your character?

Tags: tales-of-maj-eyal

I am not playing on the highest resolution monitor, and sometimes there are enemies that are off screen but "visible" to my character. Targeting them is annoying.

I know I've seen other players pan the screen around to make targeting and planning easier. What are the keyboard controls that allow me to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit the Caps Lock key to enter scroll mode. Then use the arrows keys or the numpad to scroll around the map. Hit Caps Lock again when you're done to return to normal mode.

Answer (score -1):

Better to use shift + hold left click